# Blink Animation Count: how to blink a TextView only three times

Tags: android

how to blink a TextView only 3 three times.

I tried this code,but it doesn't work.

Guys I have a textview which i need it to be blinking.

```
anim.setDuration(150);
anim.setStartOffset(50);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(3);

MainScreenActivity.txtNext.startAnimation(anim);
blinking=true;
```

Comment: What is the result of running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a xml that could be used to blink a view

**blink.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:repeatCount="3"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
        android:duration="150"
        />
</set>
```

You can call this animation like this:

```
MainScreenActivity.txtNext.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainScreenActivity, R.anim.blink))
```

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean by "blink". And by the look of your code (`MainScreenActivity.txtNext`) I'm not even sure if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Okay. That's what this does.